# how do I assign a value to a variable but of 'extract from timestmap'?

Tags: postgresql, function, timestamp, plpgsql

I have a function that inserts hours and days in a table but, I do not want it to be inserted when it is Saturday and Sunday; for which I found the extract code (isodown from timestmap 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24: mi: ss') but the problem is that when assigning the value to a variable to make my condition, it does not read it, it throws me error.

```
desde TIMESTAMP;
```

`desde:=TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-06-09 20:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss')::TIMESTAMP;`

`var_fds:=(select cast(extract(ISODOW  from  timestamp (desde::varchar)) as int));`

```
CASE WHEN var_fds<6 then
...DO SOMETHING
END;

ERROR:  error de sintaxis en o cerca de «desde»
LINE 27: ...ds:=(select cast(extract(ISODOW  from  timestamp (desde::var...
```

I also tried to just put the variable 'desde' without the varchar but still does not recognize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply assign the result of the expression:

```
var_fds := cast(extract(ISODOW  from  desde) as int);
```

As `desde` is already a `timestapm` there is no need to cast to something different.

The `timestamp` prefix in an expression is only required for constant values to make them a typed value.